# USACO Code Submission Problem - Output File Missing

Tags: output, printwriter

I'm practicing some USACO past released problems but whenever I submit my code for grading I receive the error:

Your output file (FILENAME.out):
[File missing!]

I tested every problem using this simple code, but still receive the same error:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



public class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME)));

        out.println("Hello world.");

        out.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Why would this code not create an output file?

Answer (score 2):

The USACO grading system has the output file already made in the same directory as your java solution, so all you need to do is just write to it.

In your line

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME)));
```

you should change this to

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME.out)));
```

since this is the name of the file. This does not create an actual file, but just writes to the existing one on the USACO grading system.